# Noticing integer values

Tags: java, netbeans

Need a bit of help in writing a line of code in java to notice if the integer value for a text field is a certain number (10) and then set it to another number (0) if it is that number

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect 
questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems -- but we 
will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us 
[what you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com), and where you are stuck. 
This will also help us answer your question better.

Comment: You need to include a *lot* more information. The code you've tried, what it's doing or not doing vs. what you want it to do, etc.

Comment: This is the code for a button that I have that adds one when pressed:int dd = Integer.parseInt(digitValue.getText());
        dd = dd+1;
        String ss = Integer.toString( dd);
        digitValue.setText(ss); 
        showDigitActionPerformed(evt);

Comment: Im stuck on writing code to detect if a text field has a certain value and then to bring that value to 0 if it reaches 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Retrieve the value by using

```
String tempString = nameOfTextfield.getText();
```

Then use the following (*will produce errors if a double value is not entered*):

```
double value = Double.parseDouble(tempString);
```

A simple if statement to check the value, and possibly replace the value.

```
if(value == 10){
nameOfTextfield.setText("0");
}
```

Comment: Glad to help :) Also, do take into consideration what the others pointed out. Include more information in your questions such as what you are stuck on, what you have tried, some relevant code, etc.

Comment: Will do next time, still a huge newbie, thanks again :)